# Proof about maximum amount of Spanning Trees in Complete Graph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

How do I prove that the Complete Graph with $n$ ($n$ is even) vertices can have as much as $n / 2$ disjoint spanning trees (spanning trees that does not share an edge)?

So complete graph has $n(n-1)/2$ vertices and the spanning tree has $n - 1$. Then if we divide the first number by the second one we will get the answer, but I can't get why this is correct, because any $n-1$ edge may not form the spanning tree.

Answer (score 1):

Hint do it by induction. Adding a vertex adds a natural spanning tree - find it.

Comment: @AlexJackson : If you only need a predicate, $P$, to be true on even numbers, then use $P(n-2)$ to prove $P(n)$.

Comment: Yep, I got it and then deleted my comment.

Comment: Can you finish it? I could not do it with even reading the blog linked above.

Comment: @AlexJackson No, sorry, my union is opposed to my doing your homework.

Comment: By "adding a vertex" did you mean "adding two vertices"?

Comment: @IgorRivin That's not my homework. I have fun doing math puzzles, but here I got stuck.